# INVALID NUMBER ORA-01722 with correct Data

Tags: sql, oracle

[ERROR OF THE LOG AFTER EXECUTE SQLDR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArUVy.png)I'm trying to insert numeric values in a field, but I'm getting the same error all the time INVALID NUMBER ORA-01722. I don't know where is the error because I'm inserting decimal number declared as NUMBER (18,6) for field IMP_NPVFRONT and the value is casted to this length, but it isn't working. I'm using this code:

```
echo "OPTIONS (SKIP=1)" >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo "LOAD DATA" >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo "APPEND" >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo "INTO TABLE TERM.TTERMNZI" >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' ">> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo "OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' " >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo "TRAILING NULLCOLS" >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo "(" >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " COD_CURRPL CHAR NULLIF COD_CURRPL=\"\"," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " COD_IDINST INTEGER EXTERNAL," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " COD_COUNTER CHAR NULLIF COD_COUNTER=\"\"," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " XTI_INTERNA CHAR NULLIF XTI_INTERNA=\"\"," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " COD_PRTFOLIO CHAR NULLIF COD_PRTFOLIO=\"\",">> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " COD_FAMILY CHAR NULLIF COD_FAMILY=\"\"," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " COD_GRUPO CHAR NULLIF COD_GRUPO=\"\"," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " COD_TIPOPER CHAR NULLIF COD_TIPOPER=\"\"," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " FEC_EXPIRY DATE \"DD/MM/RRRR\"," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " COD_STATUS CHAR NULLIF COD_STATUS=\"\"," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " FEC_INICIO   DATE \"DD/MM/RRRR\"," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " COD_INSTRMNT CHAR NULLIF COD_INSTRMNT=\"\"," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " COD_ENTITY CHAR NULLIF COD_ENTITY=\"\"," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " IMP_NONFMV CHAR \"to_number(:IMP_NONFMV, '999999999999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')\"," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " IMP_CAMBIO CHAR \"to_number(:IMP_CAMBIO, '999999999999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')\","  >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " COD_APLICFO CHAR,"  >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " IMP_NPVFRONT CHAR \"to_number(:IMP_NPVFRONT,'999999999999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')\"," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " FEC_PROCESO \"to_date('$3', 'DD/MM/RRRR')\" ," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " COD_FICHERIN CONSTANT \"$4\" ," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " FEC_LOADER SYSDATE ," >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " XTI_ESTADO CONSTANT 0 " >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL
echo " )" >> $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL

echo "$TEPR_HLOG Fichero de control $TEPR_NFICHCONTROLCTL generado correctamente"

echo "$TEPR_HLOG Fin Ejecucion de: $TEPR_NSCRIPT"

exit 0
```

The above produced a control file containing something like this:

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE TERM.TTERMNZI
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
 COD_CURRPL CHAR NULLIF COD_CURRPL="",
 COD_IDINST INTEGER EXTERNAL,
 COD_COUNTER CHAR NULLIF COD_COUNTER="",
 XTI_INTERNA CHAR NULLIF XTI_INTERNA="",
 COD_PRTFOLIO CHAR NULLIF COD_PRTFOLIO="",
 COD_FAMILY CHAR NULLIF COD_FAMILY="",
 COD_GRUPO CHAR NULLIF COD_GRUPO="",
 COD_TIPOPER CHAR NULLIF COD_TIPOPER="",
 FEC_EXPIRY DATE "DD/MM/RRRR",
 COD_STATUS CHAR NULLIF COD_STATUS="",
 FEC_INICIO   DATE "DD/MM/RRRR",
 COD_INSTRMNT CHAR NULLIF COD_INSTRMNT="",
 COD_ENTITY CHAR NULLIF COD_ENTITY="",
 IMP_NONFMV CHAR "to_number(:IMP_NONFMV, '999999999999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')",
 IMP_CAMBIO CHAR "to_number(:IMP_CAMBIO, '999999999999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')",
 COD_APLICFO CHAR,
 IMP_NPVFRONT CHAR "to_number(:IMP_NPVFRONT,'999999999999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')",
 FEC_PROCESO "to_date('', 'DD/MM/RRRR')" ,
 COD_FICHERIN CONSTANT "" ,
 FEC_LOADER SYSDATE ,
 XTI_ESTADO CONSTANT 0 
 )
```

Thank you in advance and sorry for my English :)

**CREATE TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE TTERMNZI 
(
  COD_IDINST VARCHAR2(150 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, COD_FICHERIN VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, FEC_PROCESO DATE 
, COD_OPERORI VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) 
, XTI_ESTADO NUMBER(1, 0) 
, COD_ESTADO NUMBER(4, 0) 
, COD_PRTFOLIO VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, COD_DEALID VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, COD_EVENT VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, COD_CURRCON VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, COD_COUNTER VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, FEC_ALTA DATE 
, FEC_MATURITY DATE 
, FEC_FRONTVAL DATE 
, FEC_RKVAL DATE 
, IMP_NPVFRNEU NUMBER(18, 6) 
, IMP_NPVBO NUMBER(18, 6) 
, IMP_NPVBOEU NUMBER(18, 6) 
, COD_CURRPL VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) 
, IMP_MVPAGO NUMBER(18, 6) 
, IMP_MVRECIBO NUMBER(18, 6) 
, IMP_MVCONSA NUMBER(18, 6) 
, IMP_MVCONEU NUMBER(18, 6) 
, COD_FAMILY VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, COD_GRUPO VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, COD_STATUS VARCHAR2(8 BYTE) 
, COD_TIPOPER VARCHAR2(4 BYTE) 
, FEC_EXPIRY DATE 
, FEC_INICIO DATE 
, COD_INSTRMNT VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, COD_ENTITY VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
, COD_APLICFO VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, FEC_LOADER DATE 
, COD_USUARIO VARCHAR2(5 BYTE) 
, XTI_INTERNA VARCHAR2(1 BYTE) 
, IMP_NONFMV NUMBER(18, 6) 
, IMP_CAMBIO NUMBER(18, 6) 
, IMP_NPVFRONT NUMBER(18, 6) 
, CONSTRAINT CTERMNZI PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    COD_IDINST 
  , COD_APLICFO 
  )
  USING INDEX 
  (
      CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CTERMNZI ON TTERMNZI (COD_IDINST ASC, COD_APLICFO 
ASC) 
      LOGGING 
      TABLESPACE ETERM01 
      PCTFREE 10 
      INITRANS 2 
      STORAGE 
      ( 
        INITIAL 65536 
        NEXT 1048576 
        MINEXTENTS 1 
        MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
        BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
      ) 
      NOPARALLEL 
  )
  ENABLE 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE ETERM01 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOPARALLEL;
```

**DATA FILE:**

```
EST;3773909;8EUK;N;RF_STARTY;IRD;BOND;S;18/10/2024;LIVE;25/09/2020;OCD 0 184534;0018234537;-2402029;1;0;MX;-2402029.000000
EST;8223589;A4805;N;SW_STARTY;IRD;IRS;B;22/12/2045;LIVE;29/09/2014;EUROPE;001345297;-217726.721335;1;0;MX;-217726.721335
```

Comment: Provide a runnable test case which produces the errors.  Update the question with the exact sqlldr commands you executed, along with the `CREATE TABLE` statement of the table into which you are importing data, plus sample input data causing the error when being loaded.  This test case should be runnable and produce the error you're asking about.

Comment: It doesn't throw any new information, only the info in the image added

Comment: You misunderstood.  You (your question) need to provide a _runnable test case_ that can be executed by anyone without any further guessing, not just the errors produced.  Where did you post the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the "TTERMNZI" table?  Where is the exact data file you imported (just a few lines needed to produce the error)?

Comment: Sorry you are right I'm not really good with sql language, it is new for me. I add the information that you ask for

Comment: Please delete all columns from your question except the 1 column that is causing the problem, which will reduce the noise and make your question clear and narrowly focused. Read [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sorry, but I'm adding the whole information that Jon Armstrong ask for, this is the table that I have, I don't know what is the problem, the issue is for the field IMP_NPVFRONT

Comment: The `echo` commands don't seem to be part of the issue so you might remove them from the question. However you could simplify this step in your process using a [here-document](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Here_documents).

Comment: IMP_NPVFRONT has the value 'MX' in both sample records, but the control file field tries to apply a `to_number` expression to it.

Comment: The datafile has 18 portions seperated by semi-colons while the control file has 21 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that IMP_NPVFRONT has the value 'MX' in both sample records, causing the error when attempting to apply the `to_number` expression on it.

| COD_CURRPL | COD_IDINST | COD_COUNTER | XTI_INTERNA | COD_PRTFOLIO | COD_FAMILY | COD_GRUPO | COD_TIPOPER | FEC_EXPIRY | COD_STATUS | FEC_INICIO | COD_INSTRMNT | COD_ENTITY | IMP_NONFMV | IMP_CAMBIO | COD_APLICFO | IMP_NPVFRONT | FEC_PROCESO | COD_FICHERIN | FEC_LOADER | XTI_ESTADO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EST | 3773909 | 8EUK | N | RF_STARTY | IRD | BOND | S | 18/10/2024 | LIVE | 25/09/2020 | OCD 0 184534 | 0018234537 | -2402029 | 1 | 0 | MX | -2402029.000000 |  |  |  |
| EST | 8223589 | A4805 | N | SW_STARTY | IRD | IRS | B | 22/12/2045 | LIVE | 29/09/2014 | EUROPE | 001345297 | -217726.721335 | 1 | 0 | MX | -217726.721335 |  |  |  |

When I set IMP_NPVFRONT `filler` (so it is skipped), the file loaded. You will need to check your data and how it should be loaded. (I also added a header to the test file to match `OPTIONS (SKIP=1)` in the control file.)

Other points:

1. `COD_CURRPL CHAR NULLIF COD_CURRPL=""` and all other fields that are set to null if there is no value - that doesn't seem to achieve anything so I removed the 'nullif' expressions.
2. `COD_IDINST INTEGER EXTERNAL` - this datatype is for binary data, not text characters representing numbers. To be honest I've never used it. According to the log file, SQL*Loader is ignoring it, and the column is a string anyway.

```
OPTIONS (SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE TTERMNZI
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
 COD_CURRPL CHAR,
 COD_IDINST CHAR,
 COD_COUNTER CHAR,
 XTI_INTERNA CHAR,
 COD_PRTFOLIO CHAR,
 COD_FAMILY CHAR,
 COD_GRUPO CHAR,
 COD_TIPOPER CHAR,
 FEC_EXPIRY DATE "DD/MM/RRRR",
 COD_STATUS CHAR,
 FEC_INICIO DATE "DD/MM/RRRR",
 COD_INSTRMNT CHAR,
 COD_ENTITY CHAR,
 IMP_NONFMV CHAR "to_number(:IMP_NONFMV, '999999999999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')",
 IMP_CAMBIO CHAR "to_number(:IMP_CAMBIO, '999999999999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')",
 COD_APLICFO CHAR,
 IMP_NPVFRONT filler, --CHAR "to_number(:IMP_NPVFRONT,'999999999999999999D999999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = ''.,''')",
 FEC_PROCESO "to_date('', 'DD/MM/RRRR')" ,
 COD_FICHERIN CONSTANT "" ,
 FEC_LOADER SYSDATE,
 XTI_ESTADO CONSTANT 0 
 )
```